# System Date Changes to correct time but year 8113

Tags: windows-7, system, malware, virus

Every couple of days (2 times a week) a desktop (Win. 7) starts up with my date-time updated.  The time, date & month is correct but in year 8113.  This makes several programs like Word/Excel working inappropriate & crashing.

BIOS/CMOS battery has been replaced, several antivirus programs had scanned & find find any virusses.  No malware or suspicious software is installed.

Does it sounds familiar to someone ?

I would appreciate any help or advice.

Thanks !

Comment: The best thing is to restore Windows at a previous working state or to format, if you have a virus what can we do. It is generally difficult to affirm that we don't have any suspicious software, even some widely used software are doing bad things

Answer (score 1):

I know you would probably like an answer that tackles the origin of your problem. Unfortunately I don't see where this could come from.

Instead, I wanted to suggest that you check your time-synchronization. Windows can sync with time servers and does so in a predefined interval.

You could try to change the time-server and to change the interval.

The time-server can be changed like this:
http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7maintenance/windows-seven-7-sync-system-clock-with-internet-time-how-to/

The interval has to be changed by altering a registry key, namely
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time
\TimeProviders\NtpClient
(It is in seconds, so 86400 is the value for an interval of 1 day!).

Maybe it's not a fix of the originating problem, but frequent updates of your system time should reduce the resulting problems.

Comment: If it could be done on start-up it would be great, but waiting untill time is changed or synch every 30 s isn't a solution for the problem.  But it was a very good suggestion.  Thx